# Getting KeyError while appending kwargs to list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, keyerror, keyword-argument

I have a function which searches for relationships inside each paragraph of a text file. If found, it returns the relationship found with the paragraph and searches if there is any colour present in that paragraph. A sample of the 
 metadata.csv file which searches for relationship in paragraphs is as follows:

```
Blister     Base Web    PVC/PVDC
Blister     Foil         Aluminium
Blister     Base Web    PVC/PVDC
Blister     Foil         Aluminium
Vial        Glass       Borosilicate Glass
Vial        Stopper     Bromobutyl Rubber
Vial        Cap         Aluminium
```

The sample text file is as follows:

```
The tablets are filled into cylindrically shaped bottles made of white coloured
polyethylene. The volumes of the bottles depend on the tablet strength and amount of
tablets, ranging from 20 to 175 ml. The screw type cap is made of white coloured
polypropylene and is equipped with a tamper proof ring.

PVC/PVDC blister pack

Blisters are made in a thermo-forming process from a PVC/PVDC base web. Each tablet
is filled into a separate blister and a lidding foil of aluminium is welded on. The blisters
are opened by pressing the tablets through the lidding foil. PVDC foil is in contact with
the tablets.

Aluminium blister pack

Blisters are made in a cold-forming process from an aluminium base web. Each tablet is
filled into a separate blister and a lidding foil of aluminium is welded on. The blisters
are opened by pressing the tablets through the lidding foil.
```

The function to extract this is as follows:

```
import csv
import re
import os
#import pdb         
def extractor(filepath):
    #pdb.set_trace()
    #pdb.set_trace()    
    TEXT_WITHOUT_COLOUR = 'Stage {counter} : Package Description: {sen} Values: {values}'
    TEXT_WITH_COLOUR = TEXT_WITHOUT_COLOUR + ','  ' Colour: {colour}'
    colours = ['White', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Black', 'Brown', 'Silver', 'Purple', 'Navy blue', 'Gray', 'Orange', 'Maroon', 'pink', 'colourless', 'blue']
    counter = 1
    result = [] 
    unique_desc = [] #every unique description is stored 
    outputs      = [] 
    with open(filepath, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data=f.read()
        paragraphs=data.split("\n\n")
    inputfile = r"C:\Users\metadata.csv"                
    inputm = []

    with open(inputfile, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
        for row in reader:
            #types = row.split(',')
            inputm.append(row)

    final_ref = [] 
    for lists in inputm:
        final_ref.append(str(lists[0]).split(','))
    def is_missing(words, sen):
        for w in words:
            if w.lower() not in sen.lower():
                return True
        return False



    #pdb.set_trace()
    for sen in paragraphs:
        for words in final_ref:

#            print(sen)
#            print("HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            if is_missing(words, sen):
                continue

            kwargs = {
                'counter': counter,
                'sen': sen,
                'values': str(words)
            }

            if (words[0] == 'Bottle') or (words[0]=='Vial') or (words[0] =='Container') or (words[0] =='Ampoules') or (words[0] =='Occlusive Dressing'):
                for wd in colours:
                    if wd.lower() in sen.lower():
                        kwargs['colour'] = wd
                        break
                text_const = TEXT_WITH_COLOUR
            else:
                text_const = TEXT_WITHOUT_COLOUR

            result.append(text_const.format(**kwargs).replace('\n', '').replace('\t', ''))

#         


            for desc in result:

                compare = re.search(r'Package Description:(.*?)Values:',desc).group(1).replace(' ','') #clean spaces

                if compare in unique_desc:  

                    group = str(unique_desc.index(compare)+1) #index starts in 0 and group in 1     
                    desc = re.sub('Stage \d','Group '+group, desc)
                    outputs.append(desc)

                else: 

                    unique_desc.append(compare)     
                    group = str(len(unique_desc))    #new group

                    desc = re.sub('Stage \d','Group '+group, desc)
                    outputs.append(desc)
                    counter+=1
                    #continue
                    #break



            #counter += 1



#    return output            
    return (sorted(set(outputs)))
```

For few files, I am getting the error "

```
File "<ipython-input-56-f725b589f198>", line 63, in extractor
    result.append(text_const.format(**kwargs).replace('\n', '').replace('\t', ''))

KeyError: 'colour'
```

Any idea on how to fix this.

Comment: You're `text_const` format string has `{colour}` but `kwargs` doesn't contain a key `colour`. You need to ensure `kwargs` has a key `colour` or ensure `text_const` doesn't use `{colour}`.

Comment: It has right. I have declared in this line...                                                                     
                  if wd.lower() in sen.lower():
                        kwargs['colour'] = wd

Comment: Then you're condition `wd.lower() in sen.lower()` isn't matching when you get the error. Print out `wd.lower()` and `sen.lower()`. The print out before it crashes, will show you when the condition doesn't match.

Comment: True. it's not matching. But how do I tackle such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign dictionary keys to values with `.get()`:

```py
kwargs.get['colour'] = wd
```

should be

```py
kwargs['colour'] = wd
```

---

Edit regarding comments below:

```py
if (words[0] == 'Bottle') or (words[0]=='Vial') or (words[0] =='Container') or (words[0] =='Ampoules') or (words[0] =='Occlusive Dressing'):
    for wd in colours:
        if wd.lower() in sen.lower():
            kwargs['colour'] = wd
            break
    text_const = TEXT_WITH_COLOUR
else:
    text_const = TEXT_WITHOUT_COLOUR
```

should be:

```py
text_const = TEXT_WITHOUT_COLOUR

if (words[0] == 'Bottle') or (words[0]=='Vial') or (words[0] =='Container') or (words[0] =='Ampoules') or (words[0] =='Occlusive Dressing'):
    for wd in colours:
        if wd.lower() in sen.lower():
            kwargs['colour'] = wd
            text_const = TEXT_WITH_COLOUR
            break
```

Comment: Yeah actually I have tried this only. I copied the get method wrongly while pasting the code here. With kwargs['colour'] = wd, I was getting the error only

Comment: File "<ipython-input-56-f725b589f198>", line 63, in extractor
    result.append(text_const.format(**kwargs).replace('\n', '').replace('\t', ''))

KeyError: 'colour'

Comment: Print `kwargs` right before that line, and see what prints. My only thought is that `text_const.format()` function invokes the `colour` key at some point in its operation -- but that should've been caught by the error stack.

Comment: Printed kwargs before the result.append line

Comment: It came as `{'counter': 1, 'sen': 'Vials made of borosilicate glass (Ph Eur Type 1, USP Type 1 and JP).\nRubber stoppers made of bromobutyl rubber.\nAluminium caps.', 'values': "['Vial', 'Glass', 'Borosilicate Glass']"}`

Comment: I think if I add colour to the line `TEXT_WITHOUT_COLOUR = 'Stage {counter} : Package Description: {sen} Values: {values}'` it might work. Sounds logical?

Comment: In such case its because the `if (words[0] == 'Bottle') or (words[0]=='Vial') or ...:` portion validates to true, but the `if wd.lower() in sen.lower():` does not. Put `text_const = TEXT_WITH_COLOUR` before the `break` in the `if-statement` above it.

Comment: Did that. Now getting this error:  `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text_const' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Okay I declared it text_const as global but other parts of the code are breaking now when it returns NoneType

Comment: Well, that error confirms my speculations. The portion of the code `if wd.lower()` is not getting triggered. Easy fix (no need for global). Assign the `text_const = TEXT_WITHOUT_COLOUR` **before** the `if (words[0] == 'Bottle')` line, and remove the `else:` portion. You will be assigning `text_const` to `TEXT_WITHOUT_COLOUR`, and if and only if triggered, assigning `text_const` to `TEXT_WITH_COLOUR`.

Comment: Edit made to the post above.

Comment: Glad it did! :)